# Writing to files not working in some areas

Tags: java, logging, filewriter, file-writing

So I'm just practicing my java programming and wanted to utilize it to build a small little app for myself that will hold my job resume and will later be able to create budgets and stuff like that. Now on to the code itself, So i looked up many ways to write to files in java and i have been successful in doing so, the problem is that the same code i use that works fine and dandy......doesn't work in a particular part of the code, and with using my logic and knowledge of what the code is doing at that time i cannot fathom why it isn't working so i need someone to help review this and see if they caught something I'm not seeing.

```
package jobinfo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton loginB, newUserB;
    private JTextField JTFUsername;
    private JPasswordField JPFPassword;
    public Login()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("JobInfo - Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        newUserB = new JButton("New User");
        newUserB.addActionListener(this);
        newUserB.setBounds(40,280,100,30);
        loginB = new JButton("Login");
        loginB.addActionListener(this);
        loginB.setBounds(180,280,100,30);
        JLabel JLUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        JLUsername.setBounds(100,100,150,30);
        JTFUsername = new JTextField();
        JTFUsername.setToolTipText("Enter your username");
        JTFUsername.setBounds(JLUsername.getBounds().x +70,JLUsername.getBounds().y,150,30);
        JLabel JLPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        JLPassword.setBounds(100,150,150,30);
        JPFPassword = new JPasswordField();
        JPFPassword.setToolTipText("Enter your password");
        JPFPassword.setBounds(JLPassword.getBounds().x+ 70, JLPassword.getBounds().y, 150, 30);


        frame.add(loginB);
        frame.add(newUserB);
        frame.add(JLUsername);
        frame.add(JTFUsername);
        frame.add(JLPassword);
        frame.add(JPFPassword);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Login Page");
```

So this where i use and successfully write to a file. In my logs file i can see that Application has launched successfully statement.

```
        try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(
                "/Users/credant/Desktop/Programming/JILogs/AppLogs.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("--> Application has Launched successfully!");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        }catch(Exception b)
        {
            JFrame Dframe = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Dframe,
                b.getMessage(),"App Crashed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }


    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == loginB)
        {
        try{
```

So here is where the problem is, I'm doing the exact samething as the first write to a file, but upon checking my AppLogs.txt, i never see the statement "Verifying Login Credentials" yet in the IDE Console i do get a "Updated AppLogs.txt" which its code comes after the file writeup.....how is this possible, my only guess is that the file write up is failing and the catch isn't catching it, so like a silent error is thrown i guess...though i have never heard of such a thing. Heres another loop hole, if you were to have run this code, you would be presented with a Login page, the mystery error only happens if you input the incorrect credentials, but if you put the correct credentials the Log file gets update and we move on as normal......

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(
                "/Users/credant/Desktop/Programming/JILogs/AppLogs.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("--> Verifying Login Credentials");
        bw.newLine();
        System.out.println("Updated AppLogs.txt");
        boolean usernam = false;
        boolean passwor = false;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/credant/Desktop/Programming/JobInfo/AccountDatabase/Accounts.txt"));

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
           try{
               String line = scan.nextLine();
               if(line.isEmpty())
               {

               }
               else
               {
                   String checkUser[] = line.split(":");
                   if(checkUser[0].equals("Username"))
                   {
                       checkUser[1] = checkUser[1].substring(1);
                       if(checkUser[1].equals(JTFUsername.getText()))
                       {
                            bw.write("--> Username is correct");
                            bw.newLine();
                            usernam = true;

                       }
                       else
                       {
                            bw.write("--> Username is invalid, Displaying Incorrect message");
                            bw.newLine();
                            usernam = false;
                       }
                   }
                   else if(checkUser[0].equals("Password"))
                   {
                       checkUser[1] = checkUser[1].substring(1);
                       String password = new String(JPFPassword.getPassword());
                       if(checkUser[1].equals(password))
                       {
                           bw.write("--> Password is correct!");
                           bw.newLine();
                           passwor = true;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           bw.write("--> Password is invalid, Displaying Incorrect message");
                            bw.newLine();
                            passwor = false;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }catch(Exception b)
           {
               JFrame Dframe = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Dframe,
                b.getMessage(),"App Crashed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }
        if(usernam == true)
        {
            if(passwor == true)
            {
                  bw.write("--> Authorization completed, retrieving JobInfo Account page");
                  bw.newLine();
                  bw.write("--> Logged in as:"+ JTFUsername.getText());
                  bw.newLine();
                  bw.close();
                  frame.setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bw.write("--> Password is invalid, displaying invalid message.");
                bw.newLine();
                JLabel invalid = new JLabel("Invaild Credentials, Please try again.");
                invalid.setBounds(100, 310 , 100, 30);
                invalid.setForeground(Color.red);
                frame.add(invalid);
            }
        }
        else if(usernam == false)
        {
            bw.write("--> Username is invalid, displaying invalid message.");
            bw.newLine();
            JLabel invalid = new JLabel("Invaild Credentials, Please try again.");
            invalid.setBounds(100, 310 , 100, 30);
            invalid.setForeground(Color.red);
            frame.add(invalid);
        }


        }catch(Exception b)
        {
            JFrame Dframe = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Dframe,
                b.getMessage(),"App Crashed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }

        }
        else if(e.getSource() == newUserB)
        {
            try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(
                "/Users/credant/Desktop/Programming/JILogs/AppLogs.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("--> Setting up to add a new User");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        AccountCreation createAccount = new AccountCreation();
        createAccount.createAccount();
        }catch(Exception b)
        {
            JFrame Dframe = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Dframe,
                b.getMessage(),"App Crashed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Im not sure whats wrong but any suggestions would be helpful, also i know parts of the code are really bad programming, i will be revamping, using threads and what not as that what helps with certain conditions, and if there is a shorter way of writing to a file please feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `flush()` method whenever you write to a file:

for example change:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("--> Application has Launched successfully!");
bw.newLine();
bw.close();
```

to:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write("--> Application has Launched successfully!");
bw.newLine();
bw.flush();  //add this line
bw.close();
```

the best practice is to `flush` just before you `close` the `buffer`.

However if you suddenly require to close your application, you might just `flush` right after you write.

Comment: Hmm what does flush() do though?

Comment: @NOnfri method flushes the characters from a write buffer to the character or byte stream as an intended destination.

Comment: Oh okay i will go ahead and add that to the code though could that be the main reason why this failing as it is?

Comment: Placed in the flush at the parts where I'm about to close the buffer, ran the program and still the log file update is still getting bypassed.....Also do you know if theres any possibility of an error being thrown but never caught in a catch statement? i believe this could happen in other programming languages not sure if java is one of them?

Comment: i might just have the logging running on its own thread, that way all the process of writing to a file is separate from verifying the credentials.